# problems creating symbolic links in Windows10

Tags: mklink

I cannot do `mklink`, not even as administrator (account 'admin'). I get the message "You don't have sufficient privileg..." or "Access denied".
What I tried to do is this, as administrator:

```
mklink /D C:\users\staff\onedrive\firmware D:\users\staffan\firmware
```

Something I do wrong?

Comment: I have a hunch you can't use OneDrive as conventional storage for all purposes. kind of makes sense that you would not be able to include subdirectories of OneDrive in links and whatnot. have you tried it with a non-OneDrive path?

Comment: Also, are both volumes NTFS?